# Writing to socket using PHP

Tags: php, sockets

I have this code in a file `bot.php` which opens and keeps a live IRC connection:

```
<?php

// Prevent PHP from stopping the script after 30 seconds
set_time_limit(0);

// Open socket
$irc = fsockopen("localhost", 6667);

// Send AUTH
fputs($irc,"USER PHPServ PHPServ PHPServ :PHPServ\n");
fputs($irc,"NICK PHPServ\n");

// Wait, OPER and JOIN channel
sleep(5);
fputs($irc,"OPER PHPServ :password\n");
fputs($irc,"JOIN #channel\n");

// Force an endless while
while(1) {

    // Continue
    while($data = fgets($irc, 128)) {

        echo nl2br($data);
        flush();

        $ex = explode(' ', $data);

        if($ex[0] == "PING"){
            fputs($irc, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");
        }

    }

}

?>
```

How can I do a `fputs($irc,"PRIVMSG #channel :Message\n");` that will send this through `bot.php` but from another file for e.g. `rgeister.php`?

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Use a file, a database, in-memory storage, etc.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I just want to write a command to that existing connection. It can't be done?

Comment: Does "send this _through_ `bot.php`" mean to or from?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Well there is a connection already open in `bot.php`, I want to send to it from another file.

Answer (score 0):

You need a way of communicating between `bot.php` and `register.php`.

Since both run on the same machine there are easier ways than sockets. Get yourself a `.txt` file and write a message in it from `register.php` ([file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) maybe).

Then read it inside that while loop in `bot.php` ([file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) maybe). If it's empty then do nothing. If there's a message inside send it using `fputs` and then empty the file so you don't read it and send it again the next loop.

Obviously this is subject to concurrency issues. Read about [file locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking) if performance is not an issue here, and I guess it is not.